# I can't get g-spread to list all worksheets

Tags: python, gspread

On function "navigate_sheet" on line 98
line 99 does not display a list of worksheets

I am not quite sure what to try

https://pastebin.com/Mzy3R5cn

```
class InputData:
    def __init__(self):
        # use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
        self.scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
                 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
        self.creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', self.scope)
        self.client = gspread.authorize(self.creds)
        self.sheet = ""
        self.error = "[!] There was a critical error that broke the program!"
    def navigate_sheet(self):
        worksheet_list = self.sheet.worksheets()
        print(worksheet_list)
```

Expected Result for this:

> Display a List of Worksheets Actual Result:"AttributeError:
>   'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'worksheets'"

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to init the `sheet` data member.

https://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#opening-a-spreadsheet

This link can help you in initialising the sheet member

Answer (score 0):

```
    worksheet_objs = sheet.worksheets()
    worksheets_list = []
    for worksheet in worksheet_objs:
        worksheets_list.append(worksheet.title)
```

I use this to check if a worksheet is present, if so --> delete